# Which computer needs SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege to shut down a remote system?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, power-management, privileges, rpc

Say, if I want to shut down a remote computer 2 from my computer 1 using a tool like `shutdown.exe`. I keep reading that this requires [`SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/privilege-constants). What I am not clear about is which computer needs it, local computer 1 or remote computer 2 that is being shut down?

Comment: The user who performed the action

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks. I guess a process performing a remote shutdown cannot grant `SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege` to itself, so it had be done via `secpol`, right?

Answer (score 1):

From your link : "User" Right: Force shutdown from a remote system."

So it would be the user that performs the privileged shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better description of `SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege` in the Microsoft
article
[Force shutdown from a remote system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/force-shutdown-from-a-remote-system):

> This security setting determines which users are allowed to shut down a device
>   **from a remote location** on the network. This allows members of the Administrators group or specific users to manage computers (for tasks such as a restart)
>   **from a remote location**.

The permission then needs to be granted on the computer that is to be shutdown
remotely. The account that is used is the local account that corresponds
to the remote account that will issue the shutdown request.

This is only logical, since otherwise any remote account that has this permission
will be able to shutdown any computer on the local network.

The situation is clearer in a domain, when the remote user is logged-in using
a domain account that will be recognized on the target computer.

Comment: Well, you see my confusion. You are pretty much contradicting all other answers posted above. So now, which one is it? I kinda followed your logic originally, and it does make sense in case of the domain accounts being used here. But what is confusing is when you have mere workstations involved. If it's the computer that is being shutdown, two questions arise: 1) how would that remote account be known on the other workstation when shutdown is issued to verify this permission? and 2) What process on the remote system that is shutdown do I need to give `SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege` permission to?

Comment: I wrote this answer because the others seemed incorrect. 1) The remote account is known by its network credentials or by the identity it assumes on the target computer, 2) This is a property of the *effective* local/domain account on the target computer under which executes the process. The remote process presents credentials to the target which identify an account, local to the target or domain, that must have this permission.